# Menu goes under header in NavigationView

Tags: android, android-drawable, navigationview

I moved header of NavigationView from include file to contents of NavigationView (Because I needed to access widgets using synthetic), but menu items jumped up and went under header, how can I fix it? I tried disabling fitsSystemWindows but didn't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

        app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
            android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/nav_header_desc"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/user_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/profile_image"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/profile_image"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/nav_header_subtitle" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/user_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@id/user_email"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/profile_image"
                android:fontFamily="@font/uifont"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
                android:text="@string/nav_header_title"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: This Layout also included Drawer layout or not

Comment: why moved away from include file ?

Comment: @ManoharReddy Because I needed to access widgets using synthetic.

Comment: In that case may be better completely remove Navigation view and use your own view .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your relative layout(header design) to different layout file:
**header.xml**

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/nav_header_desc"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/profile_image"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/profile_image"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/nav_header_subtitle" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/user_email"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/profile_image"
            android:fontFamily="@font/uifont"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
            android:text="@string/nav_header_title"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

And in your drawer screen:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


  <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" >


    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In your java file, to access header views which is inside header layout:

```
val headerView: View = nav_view.getHeaderView(0)
headerView.user_name.text = "Some Value"
```

Comment: I am coding in Kotlin, but will use you solution, thanks.

Comment: @AVEbrahimi i also did write  code in kotlin, where have you seen java code?

Answer (score 0):

This is my layouts and work perfect: activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- AppBarLayout should be here -->
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- add app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" -->

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

app_bar_main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".activty.MainActivity">
    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: But synthetic is not accessible if I use header via include file.